# Get DISTINCT Sum of Total by WorkID with LEFT JOINs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to get the total minutes but it's not working correctly with my left joins. Is there a way to add a column that has the DISTINCT total of minutes for a given MachineDescription?

Here is the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fd99/1

```
    SELECT  Work.WorkID
          , Work.Description
          , Machine.MachineDescription
          , Name.NAME
          , Work2.RegMin
          , Work.MINUTES
    FROM    Work Work 
            JOIN Machine Machine ON Machine.MachineID = Work.MachineID
            LEFT JOIN Work2 Work2 ON Work2.WorkID = Work.WorkID
            LEFT JOIN Name Name ON Name.NameID = Work2.NameID
```

I'd like to have a column with the DISTINCT Sum of Minutes. So the the total of minutes would be '30' not '40' for WorkID 111.

My output looks like this:

```
WorkID | Description | MachineDescription | Name | RegMin | Minutes
-------------------------------------------------------------------
111      Replace Belt  Splitter            Joe    10       10
111      Replace Belt  Splitter            Bob    20       10     
112      Door Broke    Splitter            Joe    10       20
```

I want a column with the total minutes by DISTINCT WorkID like this...

```
WorkID | Description | MachineDescription | Name | RegMin | Minutes | Total Minutes
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
111      Replace Belt  Splitter            Joe    10       10         30
111      Replace Belt  Splitter            Bob    20       10         30
112      Door Broke    Splitter            Joe    10       20         30
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `SUM(DISTINCT)` has always indicated a data/logic problem when I've seen it in queries.  Can you better explain how you arrive at "30" for all three rows?  You might also explain the "40" comment as well.  I could see the value being 30, 20, 50, or 10, but not 40.

Comment: I haven't gotten '30' but didn't know if there was a way to get that result.

Comment: look at my latest edit below, is that that your after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Correlated Sub-query` to get the result. Try this.

```
SELECT Work.WorkID,
       Work.Description,
       Machine.MachineDescription,
       NAME.NAME,
       Work2.RegMin,
       Work.MINUTES,
       (SELECT Sum(DISTINCT MINUTES)
        FROM   Work w
        WHERE  w.MachineID = Machine.MachineID) Total_minutes
FROM   Work Work
       JOIN Machine Machine
         ON Machine.MachineID = Work.MachineID
       LEFT JOIN Work2 Work2
              ON Work2.WorkID = Work.WorkID
       LEFT JOIN NAME NAME
              ON NAME.NameID = Work2.NameID
```

**Output :**

```
WorkID  Description MachineDescription  NAME    RegMin  MINUTES Total_minutes
------  ----------- ------------------  ----    ------  ------- -------------
111     Sink Broken     SPLITTER        Joe     10      10      30
111     Sink Broken     SPLITTER        Bob     20      10      30
112     Door Broken     SPLITTER        Joe     10      20      30
```

Comment: I get this error: Subquery returned more than 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT  Work.WorkID
          , Work.Description
          , Machine.MachineDescription
          , Name.NAME
          , Work2.RegMin
          , Work.MINUTES
          , (SELECT (SUM(work2.RegMin) ) FROM work2 left join work on work2.workid = work.workid) - work.minutes AS TotalMinutes
    FROM    Work Work 
    JOIN Machine Machine ON Machine.MachineID = Work.MachineID
    LEFT JOIN Work2 Work2 ON Work2.WorkID = Work.WorkID
    LEFT JOIN Name Name ON Name.NameID = Work2.NameID
    GROUP BY work.workID
          , Work.Description
          , Machine.MachineDescription
          , Name.NAME
          , Work2.RegMin
          , Work.MINUTES
```

**Returns**

```
WORKID  DESCRIPTION MACHINEDESCRIPTION  NAME    REGMIN  MINUTES TOTALMINUTES
111     Sink Broken SPLITTER            Bob     20      10      30
111     Sink Broken SPLITTER            Joe     10      10      30
112     Door Broken SPLITTER            Joe     10      20      20
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really want the MINUTES not the REGMIN. I want to total per distinct MachineDescription. So (TotalMinutes: 10+20) NOT (10+10+20). If it's not possible let me know... Trying to find an easy way to do this.

Comment: So total minutes would be 30, 20, 30 with the example data you provided?

Comment: Well I want the TotalMinutes by MachineDescription but a distinct workID. Does that make sense? So I want TotalMinutes to be 30,30,30.

Comment: i think your maths is wrong, by machine description with distinct workid it would be 20, 20, 20

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your select:

```
(SELECT SUM(minutes) 
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT workid, minutes FROM WORK) W
) AS Total_Minutes
```